# Is there a way to disable touches to my iphone app for a while?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, touches

Is there a way to disable touches to my iphone app for a while?

What is the way i should do it?

Tnx

Comment: Touches in your App or on the whole device?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedInstance] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

and when you want to enable them again, call this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedInstance] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wan't to do this, because it is not user friendly.

When your app is loading something, make a view which you lay over your window. Make it gray and give it an alpha of .4 this way your screen 'looks' disabled.
You can add a spinner as extra 'loading' indication.

When you want to preform tasks at startup. Just add a startup screen.

When your task(s) is/are finished, remove the screens you do not need.